# Sudoku Solver function does not return correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, sudoku

I'm working on a Leetcode problem where a Sudoku Solver is implemented operating on a list of list of strings, returning a solved board of the same format. I have run into an issue where the function will print the solved board if I add a print statement, but when I try to return the board at that same point, it returns None.

```py
def row_legal(board,i,j,k):
    row = board[i]
    if row.count(str(k))>0:
        return False
    return True

def box_legal(board,i,j,k):
    row_num = i//3
    col_num = j//3
    box = [board[3*row_num+p][3*col_num+q] for p in range(3) for q in range(3)]
    if box.count(str(k))>0:
        return False
    return True

def col_legal(board,i,j,k):
    col = [board[l][j] for l in range(9)]
    if col.count(str(k))>0:
        return False
    return True

def is_available(board,i,j,n):
    return col_legal(board,i,j,n) and box_legal(board,i,j,n) and row_legal(board,i,j,n)
```

```py
def solver(board):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j]=='.':#recursion & backtracking section#
                for k in range(1,10):
                    if is_available(board,i,j,k):
                        board[i][j]=str(k)
                        solver(board)
                        board[i][j]='.'
                return
    return board
```

If the final line of `solver` is replaced with `print(board)`, a solution is printed. However, returning outputs `None` or if the return above returns `board`, it returns the initial board state.

Any help or ideas on why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated!

*Example board input:*

```
[["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]
```

Comment: "Why can't it return one?"—what makes you think it can't? Please read [ask].

Comment: Where are you calling solver from? I think the problem is not in this code but the code where solver is called from initially. The code should return but where are you returning the solution to?

Comment: The code won't return a board full stop, currently I have been running it in a jupyter notebook on one line as : ``` solver(board) ```

Comment: if you're returning a value you need to print(solver(board))

Comment: Jupyter notebook would print the returned object if the function  returned anything,

Comment: Ignore comment.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution :
The function `solver` does not pass up the solution when it finds one(i.e. it continues to try different values in each cell etc.), a simple fix is laid out below:

```
def solver(board):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j]=='.':#recursion & backtracking section#
                for k in range(1,10):
                    if is_available(board,i,j,k):
                        board[i][j]=str(k)
                        if solver(board):
                            return board   
                        board[i][j]='.'
                return
    return board
```